# Django allauth - Site URL issue

Tags: python, django, facebook, django-allauth

Facebook App configuration -

Basic:
App domains - `domainname.com`

Site URL - `http://domainname.com/`

Advanced:
Client OAuth Login - Yes

Web OAuth Login - Yes

Embedded Browser OAuth Login - Yes

Valid OAuth redirect URIs - `http://domainname.com/path_to_page/` [Same as LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL]

---

`settings.py`:

`SITE ID = 7`

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'https://domainname/path_to_page/'
SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False
    }
}
```

---

Database:

Social Application created
ID, Secret key added
site domain - `domainname.com`

---

I still get the following error:

`Given URL is not permitted by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not permitted by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.`

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have been stuck on this for too long now. Please help someone.